# Recurrence and Number of Ways to Make Change

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have the following problem where a shopkeeper makes change for $n$ cents by placing one coin at a time on the counter, keeping a running total; pennies, nickels, and dimes are available.  Let $C_n$ be the number of ways to make change for $n$ cents.  For example, $C_6$ is 3, since there are 3 possible lists: 111111, 51, and 15.  Write a recurrence for $C_n$.

I am having difficulty formalizing the pattern that emerges from $C_1$, $C_2$,..., $C_n$.  It seems that there is one, but I'm not sure how to describe it.  Can anyone offer a suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the last coin put down.  It can be a penny, or a nickel, or ... So to make $n$ cents you could add a penny to $n-1$ cents or a nickel to $n-5$ cents, or ....